# ReferenceError: OpenLayers is not defined while using osm layer

Tags: compiler-errors, openstreetmap, openlayers-3

I am using openLayer3 and osm for the map now trying to draw polylines on the the map when i do so

1:the poly lines are not displayed and also i am getting the error in browser has 
ReferenceError: OpenLayers is not defined

Below is the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rotation example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.2/build/ol.js"></script>
<script>
<!-- code to draw the polyline on the map-->

    var lineLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Line Layer");
    map.addLayer(lineLayer);
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(lineLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path));
    var points = new Array(
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(103.987305, 1.355333),
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(103.987262, 1.354432)
    );

    var line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points);
    var style = {
        strokeColor: 'white',
        strokeOpacity: 0.5,
        strokeWidth: 5
    };
    var lineFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(line, null, style);
    lineLayer.addFeatures([lineFeature]);

    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            }),
          lineLayer 
        ],

        target: 'map',
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                collapsible: false,

            })
        }),
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([103.986908, 1.353199]),
            rotation: 68*Math.PI/180,
            zoom: 18
        })
    });



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am  a newbie please say where i am going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rotation example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:80%; height:80%; position:fixed; border: 1px solid;" id="map"></div>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.2/build/ol.js"></script>
<script>

    var lineString = new ol.geom.LineString([
        [103.985150, 1.349480],
        [103.985656, 1.350743]
    ]);
    lineString.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

    var lineLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [new ol.Feature({
                geometry: lineString,
                name: 'Line'
            })]
        }),
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'yellow',
                opacity: 0.5,
                width: 15
            })
        })
    });

    var view = new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([103.986908, 1.353199], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 18
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            }),
            lineLayer
        ],
        target: 'map',
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                collapsible: false
            })
        }),
        view: view
    });



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that OpenLayers 2 and 3 have different APIs. Your code is in OpenLayers 2 and you have loaded OpanLayers 3(ol.js) script. For ol3 example, look at the source [here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/localized-openstreetmap.html) .
If you are using OpenLayers 2, use following syntax to declare the map.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Rotation example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script src="http://dev.openlayers.org/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script>
<!-- code to draw the polyline on the map-->

var   map = new OpenLayers.Map({
   div: "map",
  allOverlays: true
});

var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Streets", {visibility: false});

// note that first layer must be visible
map.addLayers([osm, gmap]);

map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
map.zoomToMaxExtent();



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there i just have the demo please say me that should i change the cdn is what it mean

Comment: if add the CDN of openlayer3 i am getting the error has  map is undefined please help me to make the changes in above sample to get it working

Comment: @DhanaLaxshmi Try using src="http://dev.openlayers.org/OpenLayers.js" instead of src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.2/build/ol.js" in your code

Comment: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:63342/OPenLayer3/rotateMap/dev.openlayers.org/OpenLayers.js"
OpenLayers.js
ReferenceError: ol is not defined please help

Comment: no luck i am getting the error has 
ReferenceError: ol is not defined
var map = new ol.Map({

Comment: Sorry. I didn't read that part of your code. Again you have used OpenLayers 3 to declare the map. I edited my answere how to do ths with OpenLayers 2. Look at the API documantation for additional controls. http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers-js.html

Comment: but i wanted to use openlayer3 to accomplish it can i do it if yes please point me some sample to do it please

Comment: I did mention a link to ol3 example in my answer. You can view the page source of that example to see how it's done. Here you can find many ol3 examples. http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/

Comment: ho sorry i did not see that i will try this